# Session Set But Not Accessing Other Page

Tags: php, session, server, localhost

Here's my login code where I set the session:

```
<?php

session_start();

foreach ($query_result as $rows) {
    if (($rows['admin_username'] == $username) && ($rows['admin_password'] == $password)) {
        $_SESSION['valid'] = true;
        $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $match_flag = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

And it is my next file code where session is not accessible:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo " session value username is: ";
    var_dump($_SESSION['username']); exit();
?>
```

It works perfectly on localhost but when I run it on the server, it will print NULL in session values.

Please help me regarding this issue.

Comment: comment out the session_start() in the second file because you are restarting the session there.

Comment: @sunny1304 I did that but same thing happening. Session value is null. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use error reporting and check if it shows any error.

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');    
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: I am creating session at the start of the file and accessing also on start of the page. but the session is not set.

Comment: Try printing $_SESSION inside if condition before break in the login code and check that value is set or not.

Comment: I want to redirect page using header('Location: myURLhere') but I got this error  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by.